# Best working solution to develop one project on Xcode using two Mac, Synology NAS, Git and Bitbucket?

Tags: xcode, git, bitbucket, synology

So far, I am developing using a MacMini. The code is automatically saved on the local SSD repository (localized inside CloudStation folder), then automatically copied on Synology NAS. Periodically I doing commits (git) and push them to Bitbucket.

Previous set-up: 
 - MacMini.
 - Synology NAS.
 - Private project repository on Bitbucket.
 - Local project repository both on NAS and local SSD using CloudStation.

I recently bought a MacBook Pro and what to use both Mac.

I installed CloudStation and opened the source code from Synology folder. The problem is that it does not consider it as a Git repository.

As far as I understood, the git repository is the local folder on MacMini.
The one on Synology is simply a copy.

I would like to be able to code either on my MacMini, or on my MacBookPro as if I had only 1 Mac. Using Git, and pushing commits to Bitbucket.

What would be the best solution?

I think about 3 solutions:

1) Use only 1 repository localized on the NAS (with git) and access it directly (without CloudStation which is doing a copy). But this might be a problem if my local network/internet is not working, as I will not be able to access the folder. Also I may have problem if Xcode is open on both Mac at the same time...

2) Each Mac will have its own local repository (no CloudStation back-up copy, or in 2 different user CloudStation folders). When I work on one Mac, I then should commit and push to Bitbucket. Then I will be able to pull to the other Mac if need.

3) Install git server on the Synology NAS. Have local versions stored on both Mac and push/pull to/from the NAS. But will this replace Bitbucket? Can I still push to Bitbucket afterward?